# SQL Server from Ubuntu - login failed

Tags: sql-server-2008, ubuntu, sqlcmd

I have a brand new Ubuntu 12 box.  I installed unixodbc and the 64 bit linux MS SQL Server 2008 driver.

When I run

```
sqlcmd -S dbserver -U me -P secret
```

I get back

```
Login failed for user 'me'.
```

The same sqlcmd line works fine on Windows.

Mixed authentication is turned on.

I am using the correct username and password (again, same command on windows works).

I can telnet to dbserver:1433; it does not appear to be a network issue.

Comment: I have determined that I can log into a different SQL Server with this command from Ubuntu and log in OK, so it's something different at the server level.  The machine I can't log into from linux is running SQL Server 2008 R2.  The one I can log into is SQL Server 2008.

Answer (score 1):

We have Ubuntu 12.04 connecting to MSSQL. Here's what we did

```
sudo apt-get install freetds-dev freetds-bin tdsodbc -y
sudo nano /etc/freetds/freetds.conf
```

delete the test connections and add your SQL info

```
[mySQLserver]
    host = 192.168.1.5
    instance = MYSQLSERVER
    port = 1433
    tds version = 8.0
```

then run the following

```
tsql -S 192.168.1.5 -U sa 
tsql -C
isql -v MSSQL sa 'yourSqlPassword'
service --status-all
```

hope this helps

Comment: Nicely explained!